# OleDbDataReader does not read last record

Tags: c#

I see 5 records to be inserted, but only 4 are inserted. The last record is not inserted, and I can not figure out why. Copying from one database to the other. First is an access database, the second is a sql server database.

```
OleDbCommand cmd2 = new OleDbCommand();
OleDbDataReader oledbReader2;
using (cmd2 = new OleDbCommand())
{
    query = "SELECT ID, STRAATNAAM, 'NL' AS TAALCODE, PKANCODE, CITY FROM Temp_Unique_Streetnames WHERE TRIM(Temp_Unique_Streetnames.STRAATNAAM) <> '' AND ID > " + lastId.ToString() + " ORDER BY ID";
    WriteToFile(query);
    cmd2.CommandText = query;
    cmd2.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    cmd2.Connection = cn2;

    using (oledbReader2 = cmd2.ExecuteReader())
    {
        while (oledbReader2.Read())
        {
            try
            {
                counter += 1;

                query = "insert into tblgeo_street ( autoid, street_id, language, country, city, streetname, zip) values (" + counter.ToString() +
                    " , " + oledbReader2.GetValue(0).ToString() +
                    " , 'NL', 23, " + oledbReader2.GetValue(4).ToString() +
                    " , '" + oledbReader2.GetValue(1).ToString().Replace('\'', '´') + "'" +
                    " , " +  oledbReader2.GetValue(3).ToString() +  ") ";
                OleDbCommand cmd3 = new OleDbCommand(query, cn3);

                WriteToFile(query);



                cmd3.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
            catch (Exception errorException)
            {
                actionSucceedded = false;
                //eventLog1.WriteEntry("Open db threw exception " + errorException.Message);
                WriteToFile("insert tblgeo_street threw exception " + errorException.Message);
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: you're writing to SQL Server; SQL Server supports parameters - *please* use parameters rather than trying to using string hacks like `Replace`; however!  by how much does `counter` increase when you run this? what ends up in the file? does an exception get thrown? does the "insert tblgeo_street threw exception ..." text get written?

Comment: counter gets updated correct with the records written. No exception is thrown, only the 4 records from the access database are written, while there should be 5.

Comment: So counter went up by `5`? and how many lines were written via `WriteToFile`? what was `actionSucceedded`? sorry if I'm being picky, but it matters; ultimately, `ExecuteNonQuery` here is just going to do the insert; now, there are 3 things that can happen next: 1) it can be inserted normally; 2) it can throw an exception; 3) it can be inserted and then an `INSTEAD OF` trigger on the server can do *anything it likes*; I'm trying to narrow down which (btw, you should probably check for an `INSTEAD OF` trigger, too)

Comment: of course, the other possibility is that you *expected* 5 rows to come back from the original query, but your expectation was wrong and actually: only 4 rows came back from the original query - i.e. the insert is working just fine, and the problem is in the select

Comment: If I execute the select query which if first written to the logfile in the access database, it returns 5 rows. The insert queries written in the 'while (oledbReader2.Read())' loop only show 4 inserts, and only 4 inserts are actually executed.

Comment: And there is no trigger on the sql table.

Comment: if the `while (reader.Read())` was true 4 times, then 4 rows were returned; this sounds like the expectation thing - the problem here seems to be the select, not the insert